# How to realize an intermediate view to crop a UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, crop

I would like to realize an intermediate view that allow the user to select an area to crop a uiimage. The user can work with 4 corners and define a square on the uiimage.

I have already found one good sample code, but I don't know how to use it in my project.
Here you can find the sample code: 
[CanVasView+Cropping](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://iphone-apple.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/TextGrabber_iphone.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/94246-how-realize-intermediate-view-crop-uiimage.html&usg=__iEWwvsvFnmtGwavHc3h8-J7SWQU=&h=480&w=650&sz=52&hl=de&start=0&zoom=1&tbnid=7ihdJz3DGK2XYM%3a&tbnh=137&tbnw=194&ei=kdwAT6bMMsLQsgbuvLDfDw&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dcrop%2Buiimage%26um%3D1%26hl%3Dde%26client%3Dsafari%26rls%3Den%26biw%3D1024%26bih%3D629%26tbm%3Disch&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=589&vpy=302&dur=2145&hovh=193&hovw=261&tx=164&ty=95&sig=118370509000953217279&page=1&ndsp=16&ved=1t:429,r:9,s:0)

Is there anyone can help me?